# Can't figure out how to send information from one to another .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to send an array through POST and 2 variables through GET from first.php to second.php file, but I cant seem to get it to work.
For all 3 I get the error message **Undefined index**

**first.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["trys"] = 0;
    echo "<hr/><pre>".print_r($_SESSION, 1)."</pre><hr/>";
?>
<script>
//array
arrayIDs = [04, 05, 45, 45, 55]

$.ajax({
                url: 'second.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {arrayIDs: arrayIDs},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("POST !DELA!")
                }
            });

//string //x=0&y=9
url = "second.php?" + "x=" + x + "&y=" + y;
// I send it through get
</script>

<html>
//some tables data is generated from
</html>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $kliknjenX =  $_GET["x"];
    $kliknjenY =  $_GET["y"];
    $kliknjenID = $kliknjenX + "" + $kliknjenY;

    $arrayIDs = $_POST['arrayIDs'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you never actually send any `GET` data  on the request...

```
<script>
//array
arrayIDs = [04, 05, 45, 45, 55]

$.ajax({
                url: 'second.php',               // <<-- This line doesn't have GET variables
                type: 'post',
                data: {arrayIDs: arrayIDs},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("POST !DELA!")
                }
            });

url = "second.php?" + "x=" + x + "&y=" + y;       // <<-- This line does nothing
</script>

<html>
//some tables data is generated from
</html>
```

It should be:

```
<script>
//array
var arrayIDs = [04, 05, 45, 45, 55];

var x = "some_url_encoded_value";
var y = "another_encoded_value";

var destination_url = "second.php?x=" + x + "&y=" + y;    

$.ajax({
                url: destination_url,
                type: 'post',
                data: {arrayIDs: arrayIDs},
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("POST !DELA!")
                }
            });


</script>

<html>
//some tables data is generated from
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you test it:

#### first.php

```html
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["trys"] = 0;
echo "<hr/><pre>".print_r($_SESSION, 1)."</pre><hr/>";
?>

<script>
    arrayIDs = [04, 05, 45, 45, 55]

    $.ajax({
        url: 'second.php?x=0&y=9',
        type: 'post',
        data: {arrayIDs: arrayIDs},
        success: function(response){
            console.log("POST !DELA!")
        }
    });
</script>

<html>
//some tables data is generated from
</html>
```

#### second.php

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    $kliknjenX =  $_GET["x"];
    $kliknjenY =  $_GET["y"];
    $kliknjenID = $kliknjenX + "" + $kliknjenY;

    $arrayIDs = $_POST['arrayIDs'];
?>
```